# Right click on hyperlink and open the link content in new window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open the href content in new window using selenium with Action class, it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

I am using selenium 2.47.1 and chrome driver (browser version 52)

```
    WebElement abc = driver.findElement(link); 

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.contextClick(abc).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

        //builder.contextClick(abc).build().perform();
        //Actions click=builder.moveToElement(abc).contextClick();
        //click = click.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        //click.moveByOffset(10,10).click().build().perform();
      //builder.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(abc).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :-

```
builder.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(abc).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

Hope it will work...:)

Comment: it didn't work for me but it works with Robot class. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with Robot class.

Here is my code .

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
//builder.contextClick(abc).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
builder.contextClick(abc).perform();

Thread.sleep(2000);
Robot robo = new Robot();

robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the `Robot` class now. I would highly recommend not using this at it limits you when you want to run a lot of tests at once.

Try this for a new `window`:

```java
WebElement abc = driver.findElement(link); 
abc.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.RETURN);
```

Or alternatively you could open a new `tab` instead of a whole new `window`:

```
WebElement abc = driver.findElement(link); 
abc.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
```

**Note** : `Keys.CONTROL` should be replaced with `Keys.COMMAND` on mac

Comment: @RemcoW, Keys.SHIFT + Keys.Return throws a compilation error (The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) org.openqa.selenium.Keys, org.openqa.selenium.Keys). Any thoughts?

Comment: Oops, my bad. I've been using too much Python. Replace `+` with `,`. I've also fixed the answer.